# MAMP doesn't have SQLite

Tags: php, macos, apache, sqlite, mamp

I've installed and reinstalled MAMP and it doesn't seem like sqlite is being included. I've searched the httpd.conf with no results. I thought I was supposed to add the

```
extension=php_pdo.so
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.so
extension=php_sqlite.so
```

but the extensions aren't even in the MAMP directory so adding the above lines does nothing. Based on the MAMP website documentation SQLite is included in the install, but I'm not seeing it anywhere and I'm having no luck getting it to work. The issue arises when I load a page that refers to the SQLiteDatabase class and my php error log says

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SQLiteDatabase' not found in /var/www/queries.php on line 67
```

Comment: isnt mamp, apache, MySQL and PHP.  Not SQLite

Comment: Is queries.php code you wrote or someone else?  What is the class `SQLiteDatabase` supposed to be?  It's not a default PHP class.  For SQLite, you would use `new SQLite3()`

Comment: @JonTaylor yes, that's the acronym, but it comes with sqlite according to their website http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/faq/which-php-modules-are-included

drew, yes, I wrote "queries.php" and SQLiteDatabase is a php class as seen here http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlite.php

Answer (score 2):

No, MAMP does not have SQLite. Not sure why you say that. Based on the [MAMP website](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp/index.html) documentation SQLite is included, but actually list the packages and SQLite is not there.

Note that SQLite is installed by default on OS X as part of the operating system (as well as Apache and PHP).

Comment: pdo_sqlite is listed on the documentation http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/faq/which-php-modules-are-included

Comment: I wasn't saying that SQLite is installed from the MAMP install, I was saying that the module was supposed to be installed, which is from the documentation I listed above.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue based on @drew010's comments. Even though SQLiteDatabase is listed on the PHP website, it doesn't seem like it's working properly. I changed to new SQLite3() and it seems to be working now.